# In Kruskal's Algorithm, why does the union procedure check whether r_x == r_y since the opposite was required to call union()?

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm, union-find

In Algorithms [DPV] Section 5.1.3, the authors outlined Kruskal's Algorithm. In the algorithm itself, while iterating through all edges on the graph, they compare whether find(u) != find(v). If so, they eventually call the union() procedure on u and v. In union there is a comparison of r_x and r_y which is essentially find(x) and find(y) from the for loop in "kruskal(G,w)". Why are they checking whether find(x) == find(y) in union if the condition for calling union was that find(x) != find(y)?

```
procedure kruskal(G,w):
for all u in V:
    makeset(u)
X={}
sort the edges E by weight
for all edges {u,v} in E:
    if find(u) != find(v)
        add edge {u,v} to X
        union(u,v)


procedure union(x,y):
r_x = find(x)
r_y = find(y)
if r_x = r_y: return
....more code here
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the information it contains lacks sufficient detail to allow anyone to answer the question.

Comment: Please let me know what gaps you'd need me to fill. I could add the rest of the union procedure, but not sure what more info would help (given my lack of knowledge!) Additionally, I could add more background information regarding Kruskal's algorithm, but I also imagine it would be better if the answerer already knew that information. Cheers!

Comment: Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of **sample input**, **expected output**, **actual output**, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I see, I guess I don't have a problem with the code. It works just fine. I'm just not sure if removing that last comparison in union() would break the code on some edge case.